# Change of ease in animate(), Jquery, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I tried changing the ease I also tried using the jquery ui easing package, to try with other easings but it doesn't work, I just want to put it in 'linear'.

```
$('#slidemenu ul > li > a').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var ref = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html').stop().animate({
            scrollTop:$(ref).offset().top
        },800,'linear');
        return false;
    });
```

I tried a lot of easing, I reviewed the code for `animate()`, but I didn't get anything usefull, I tried changing `.on('click',...` for just `.click()`, to if there was any difference but nothing, I tried changing the order of the parameters of `animate()`, so at this point I don't know waht else to change.

Comment: Does this work? `$( "element" ).animate({...}, { duration: 800, easing: 'linear'});`

Comment: Code, as provided, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7u1eovnt/

Comment: Remove `.stop()`, directly `$('html').animate`

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the 'a' element was in a 'li', so i deleted all the 'li', and it worked.